# Sigar ProcCpu gather method always returns 0 for percentage value

Tags: java, cpu, percentage, zero, sigar

I'm using Sigar to try and get the CPU and memory usage of individual processes (under Windows).  I am able to get these stats correctly for the system as a whole with the below code :

```
Sigar sigar = new Sigar();

long totalMemory = sigar.getMem().getTotal() / 1024 /1024;
model.addAttribute("totalMemory", totalMemory);

double usedPercentage = sigar.getMem().getUsedPercent();
model.addAttribute("usedPercentage", String.format( "%.2f", usedPercentage));

double freePercentage = sigar.getMem().getFreePercent();
model.addAttribute("freePercentage", String.format( "%.2f", freePercentage));

double cpuUsedPercentage = sigar.getCpuPerc().getCombined() * 100;
model.addAttribute("cpuUsedPercentage", String.format( "%.2f", cpuUsedPercentage));
```

This displays the following quite nicely in my web page :

Total System Memory : 16289 MB 
Used Memory Percentage : 66.81 % 
Free Memory Percentage : 33.19 % 
CPU Usage : 30.44 %

Now I'm trying to get info from individual processes such as Java and SQL Server and, while the memory is correctly gathered, the CPU usage for both processes is ALWAYS 0.  Below is the code I'm using :

```
Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
List<ProcessInfo> processes = new ArrayList<>();

ProcessFinder processFinder = new ProcessFinder(sigar);
long[] javaPIDs = null;
Long sqlPID = null;

try
{
    javaPIDs = processFinder.find("Exe.Name.ct=" + "java.exe");
    sqlPID = processFinder.find("Exe.Name.ct=" + "sqlservr.exe")[0];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{}

int i = 0;

while (i < javaPIDs.length)
{
    Long javaPID = javaPIDs[i];
    ProcessInfo javaProcess = new ProcessInfo();
    javaProcess.setPid(javaPID);
    javaProcess.setName("Java");

    ProcMem javaMem = new ProcMem();
    javaMem.gather(sigar, javaPID);
    javaProcess.setMemoryUsage(javaMem.getResident() / 1024 / 1024);

    MultiProcCpu javaCpu = new MultiProcCpu();
    javaCpu.gather(sigar, javaPID);
    javaProcess.setCpuUsage(String.format("%.2f", javaCpu.getPercent() * 100));

    processes.add(javaProcess);

    i++;
}

if (sqlPID != null)
{
    ProcessInfo sqlProcess = new ProcessInfo();
    sqlProcess.setPid(sqlPID);
    sqlProcess.setName("SQL Server");

    ProcMem sqlMem = new ProcMem();
    sqlMem.gather(sigar, sqlPID);

    sqlProcess.setMemoryUsage(sqlMem.getResident() / 1024 / 1024);

    ProcCpu sqlCpu = new MultiProcCpu();
    sqlCpu.gather(sigar, sqlPID);
    sqlProcess.setCpuUsage(String.format( "%.2f", sqlCpu.getPercent()));

    processes.add(sqlProcess);
}

model.addAttribute("processes", processes);
```

I have tried both `ProcCpu` and `MultiProcCpu` and both of them always return 0.0 even if I can see Java using 15% CPU in task manager.  The documentation on the Sigar library is virtually non existent but the research i did tells me that i appear to be doing this correctly.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue while continuing to search online.  Basically, the sigar library can only retrieve the correct CPU values after a certain time.  My issue is that i was initializing a new Sigar instance every time the page was displayed.  I made my Sigar instance global to my Spring controller and now it returns correct percentages.

Comment: can you please provide your individual processes metrics collection implementation? I am facing the same issue as you have faced.

Comment: I honeslty gave up.  I tried JavaSysMon and it also crashes the JVM at some point even with Java 11.

Comment: Sorry, read that late last night lol.  I did manage to make the CPU usage work (although the values were questionable) but i gave up using java code in any form to get this kind of info because it always crashes the JVM at some point for some reason.  I can share my code if you want but i have to warn you that, from my experience, those types of libraries are unreliable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any way to calculate the CPU usage, memory usage, and disk I/O of the particular process id?

Comment: Currently am working on a project to calculate the java application's CPU usage, memory, disk I/O and etc. I would be really grateful if you could help me to give some idea, how can I calculate above mentioned metrics

Comment: I had initially given up on Sigar in favor of JavaSysMon.  Unfortunately i no longer have this code but i can provide the JavaSysMon code i still have which will give you the memory usage of the Java.exe processe(s) if you want.

Comment: Yes, please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185326/discussion-between-martin-and-gowthamy-vaseekaran).